# Angular calls ngAfterContentInit for each element in ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

My Angular 11 (Ioinc 5) application has 2 components: A `ContainerComponent` and a `BoxComponent`.
Both components are completely translucent (`template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'`)
The container component needs to keeps track of the number of box components that a third component places into it.
My solution fails when the third component uses *ngFor to place the boxes into the container (Option B below)

**`container.component.ts`**

```
import { Component, ContentChildren, QueryList, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BoxComponent } from './box.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'container',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
  styleUrls: ['container.component.scss'],
})
export class ContainerComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  // track the number of boxes
  private count: number = 0;

  @ContentChildren(BoxComponent)
  private boxes!: QueryList<BoxComponent>;
  
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.count++;
    console.log(count);  // Result see below
  }
}
```

A third component places `n` `BoxComponent`s into a `ContainerComponent`.

**Option A: n boxes hardcoded into template of third component**

```
<container>
    <box>Box 1</box>
    <box>Box 2</box>
    // ...
    <box>Box n</box>
</container>
```

**Option B: n boxes added into the template of the third component using *ngFor directive**

```
<container *ngFor="let box of boxes">
    <box>{{box.label}}</box>
</container>
```

**Difference between option A and option B**

When using option A, Angular calls `ngAfterContentInit` only once and the result is

```
count = n
```

When using option B, Angular calls `ngAfterContentInit` n times and the `count` is always 1.

```
count = 1, 1, ..., 1    // n times
```

I find this behavior very strange because that means that Angular creates a new instance of `ContainerComponent` for each `BoxComponent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is the right behaviour. The ngFor directive will iterate through the *boxes* list, creating one instance of the injected component for each element.

Maybe the behaviour you expect will be achieved if you put ngFor in the box component:

```
<container>
  <box *ngFor="let box of boxes">{{box.label}}</box>
</container>
```

Cheers!